# error while creating node red docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

i am trying to create node-red docker image with alpine version of node 12.18.4 i get the following error

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.18.4 (node-v72 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

content in my docker file

```
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /root/.node-red
WORKDIR /root/.node-red
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
CMD ["node-red"]
```

content of my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "node-red",
    "description": "sample",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "node-red": "^1.2.9"
    }
}
```

how do i fix the issue of python dependency, what will be the consequences of deploying such image to production.
any help is appreciated, thanks!

update:
after modifying the json file as suggested, i get the following error

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.121-linuxkit
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

later i modified my docker file as

```
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /root/.node-red
WORKDIR /root/.node-red
COPY package.json .
RUN apk update && apk add python && apk add g++ make
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
CMD ["node-red"]
```

with the above json file while building the docker image i get the below error

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@12.18.4 (node-v72 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
In file included from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'void Nan::AsyncQueueWorker(Nan::AsyncWorker*)':
../../nan/nan.h:2232:62: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'void (*)(uv_work_t*)' {aka 'void (*)(uv_work_s*)'} to 'uv_after_work_cb' {aka 'void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
 2232 |     , reinterpret_cast<uv_after_work_cb>(AsyncExecuteComplete)
      |                                                              ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:53,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: At global scope:
/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.4/include/node/node.h:608:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from 'void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)' {aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)'} to 'node::addon_register_func' {aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)'} [-Wcast-function-type]
  608 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
      |                                           ^
/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.4/include/node/node.h:642:3: note: in expansion of macro 'NODE_MODULE_X'
  642 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:378:1: note: in expansion of macro 'NODE_MODULE'
  378 | NODE_MODULE(bcrypt_lib, init);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is missing the python interpreter, you need to install it. After that you will also miss the c/c++ tools, so you need to install them as well.

```
RUN apk update && apk add python alpine-sdk
```

so the dockerfile will look like this

```
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /root/.node-red
WORKDIR /root/.node-red
COPY package.json .
RUN apk update && apk add python alpine-sdk
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
CMD ["node-red"]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i have modified the question after trying out your suggestion, can you please have a look.

Comment: This are warnings from the compile of the c/c++ libraries. Try the node-red form the container, it worked for me.

Comment: sorry, i did not completely understand what you meant by "Try the node-red form the container".

Comment: You have the image built (check with `docker image ls`. If so, start a container form it and test your application. Unless there are other errors, the warnings are not preventing the installation.

Comment: yes, the above warnings/errors are not preventing the installation, the image is being deployed successfully, i was wondering if there is a way to kind of fix those warnings/errors, thanks.